# Object to process touch event but also let it through

Tags: event-handling, qml, qt5, touch-event

I want to create an object that will work like `MultiPointTouchArea` (so it will have touchUpdated signal) but also it would not steal touches, so that objects placed beneath it will receive the touch events as well.

The solution may require creating C++ object.

Is there a simple way to create such object? Is it possible to process (touch) events without "stealing" them? Any hint will be appreciated.

---

Here is an example of what I am trying to do. I want to touch top `Rectangle` but at the same time I want both `MultiPointTouchArea`s process touches:

```
import QtQuick 2.3
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 300
    height: 300

    Rectangle {
        id: rectangle1
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        width: 150
        height: width
        color: "red"
        MultiPointTouchArea {
            anchors.fill: parent
            mouseEnabled: false
            onTouchUpdated: {
                console.log("Bottom touch area contains:",
                            touchPoints.length,
                            "touches.")
            }
        }
    }
    Rectangle {
        id: rectangle2
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        width: 100
        height: width
        color: "blue"
        MultiPointTouchArea {
            anchors.fill: parent
            mouseEnabled: false
            onTouchUpdated: {
                console.log("Top touch area contains:",
                            touchPoints.length,
                            "touches.")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If I will find working solution I will post it here. I will be trying now to implement [Mitch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/904422/mitch)'s [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35323454/5163799).

Comment: Have you tried setting `MultiPointTouchArea.mouseEnabled` to false?

Comment: @mkrus I have tried. It is not working.

Answer (score 2):

You can subclass `QQuickItem` and override the [`touchEvent()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qquickitem.html#touchEvent) function:

> This event handler can be reimplemented in a subclass to receive touch events for an item. The event information is provided by the event parameter.

You'll probably need to explicitly set [`accepted`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qevent.html#accepted-prop) to `false` to ensure that the item doesn't steal the events:

> Setting the accept parameter indicates that the event receiver wants the event. Unwanted events might be propagated to the parent widget. By default, isAccepted() is set to true, but don't rely on this as subclasses may choose to clear it in their constructor.

---

I can verify that the above will result in the lower touch area taking all events after the press (tested on an Android phone). In that case, you'll need to filter the events somehow. One way to do this is, inside your QQuickItem subclass, declare a property that will be used to point to the lower touch area. When that property changes, install an event filter on the touch area:

**main.cpp:**

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QtQuick>

class CustomTouchArea : public QQuickItem
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QQuickItem *targetTouchArea READ targetTouchArea WRITE setTargetTouchArea NOTIFY targetTouchAreaChanged)

public:
    CustomTouchArea() :
        mTargetTouchArea(0) {
    }

    bool eventFilter(QObject *, QEvent *event) {
        if (event->type() == QEvent::TouchUpdate) {
            qDebug() << "processing TouchUpdate...";
        }
        // other Touch events here...

        return false;
    }

    QQuickItem *targetTouchArea() const {
        return mTargetTouchArea;
    }

    void setTargetTouchArea(QQuickItem *targetTouchArea) {
        if (targetTouchArea == mTargetTouchArea)
            return;

        if (mTargetTouchArea)
            mTargetTouchArea->removeEventFilter(this);

        mTargetTouchArea = targetTouchArea;

        if (mTargetTouchArea)
            mTargetTouchArea->installEventFilter(this);

        emit targetTouchAreaChanged();
    }

signals:
    void targetTouchAreaChanged();

private:
    QQuickItem *mTargetTouchArea;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);

    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    qmlRegisterType<CustomTouchArea>("App", 1, 0, "CustomTouchArea");

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));

    return app.exec();
}

#include "main.moc"
```

**main.qml:**

```
import QtQuick 2.3
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

import App 1.0

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 300
    height: 300

    Rectangle {
        id: rectangle1
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        width: 150
        height: width
        color: "red"
        MultiPointTouchArea {
            id: touchArea
            anchors.fill: parent
            mouseEnabled: false
            onTouchUpdated: {
                console.log("Bottom touch area contains:",
                            touchPoints.length,
                            "touches.")
            }
        }
    }
    Rectangle {
        id: rectangle2
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        width: 100
        height: width
        color: "blue"
        CustomTouchArea {
            targetTouchArea: touchArea
            anchors.fill: parent
        }
    }
}
```

You can read more about event filters [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#installEventFilter).

Comment: I have a problem with this. I can override `touchEvent()` function but if I call `setAccepted(false)` I will stop receiving events and then they will be sent to objects below. It seems that the same `QEvent` can only be used by one object at a time.

Comment: True, I didn't test that. The answer has been updated.