# How to handle pressed and released signals in overlapping Mousareas?

Tags: qt, qml, qt-quick, qt5.5

I want to handle pressed and released signals in two overlapping Mouseareas.

Brief explanation of my case is as follows:

I have two mouse areas M1 and M2. M1 is contained by a rectangle, which serves as a button. It has a fixed size, e.g.100x100. M2 fills the whole screen and definitely larger in size than M1. I can set the z properties of M1 and M2 arbitrarily. I need to handle pressed and released signals in both of these Mouseareas.

Is it possible in QtQuick and if so, how?

```
import QtQuick 2.5
Item {
    visible: true
    width:1280
    height:720

    Rectangle {
        color: "blue"
        width: 100; height: 100
        z:1
        MouseArea {
            id:m1
            anchors.fill: parent
            onPressed : {
                mouse.accepted = false
                console.log("pressed m1")
            }
            onReleased: {
                console.log("released m1")
            }
        }
    }

    MouseArea {
        id: m2
        anchors.fill: parent
        onPressed : {
            console.log("pressed m2")
        }
        onReleased: {
            console.log("released m2")
        }
    }
}
```

I want to get pressed and released for both Mouseareas when m1 is pressed and released.

(Qt Version 5.5)

Comment: Why not show anything you have tried?

Comment: Sounds quite similar to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35312255/object-to-process-touch-event-but-also-let-it-through. It's regarding touch areas, but the same solution should apply.

Comment: The reference to eventfilters was very helpful and it goes into the right direction and suits very well to my actual use-case!

Answer (score 1):

After the comments in first answer. What`s about something like this:

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
    visible: true
    width:1280
    height:720

    Rectangle {
        color: "blue"
        width: 100; height: 100
        z:1
        MouseArea {
            id:m1
            anchors.fill: parent
            propagateComposedEvents: true
            onPressed : {
                mouse.accepted = false
                console.log("pressed m1")
            }
            onReleased: {
                console.log("released m1")

            }
        }
    }

    MouseArea {
        id: m2
        anchors.fill: parent
        onPressed : {
            console.log("pressed m2")
        }
        onReleased: {
            console.log("released m2")
            m1.released(mouse);
        }
    }
}
```

This prints out what you want.

Comment: @OnurA But when mouse is pressed and released outside m1, it shows `pressed m2, released m2, released m1`. Should it not be just `pressed m2, released m2`?

Comment: Yes you are right. Actually this method answers more or less my question, but it is not something I would use in my application. So I needed the bigger mousearea for user inputs for the whole screen. However, I solved my problem by removing m2 and using an eventfilter onQQuickView Item. So if someone proposes this as answer I will accept it as the correct answer for sure!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `id`s cannot begin with capital letters, so your `MouseArea`s can't be `M1` and `M2`. Instead they have to be m1 and m2.

```
import QtQuick 2.3

Rectangle {
    id: root
    width: 400
    height: 300

    Rectangle {
        id: m1Container
        width: 100
        height: 100
        color: "blue"
        z: 1

        MouseArea {
            id: m1
            anchors.fill: parent
            hoverEnabled: true

            onPressed: {
                mouse.accepted = false
                console.log("m1 pressed")
            }
            onReleased: {
                console.log("m1 released")
            }
        }
    }

    MouseArea {
        id: m2
        anchors.fill: parent

        onPressed: {
            console.log("m2 pressed")
        }
        onReleased: {
            console.log("m2 released")
            if(m1.containsMouse) {
                m1.released(mouse)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit**: I have borrowed the idea of `m1.released(mouse)` from the answer by sk2212, and tweaked a little to handle the case when the mouse is outside of `m1` and is pressed and released.

Comment: Since I wanted to keep it simple, I did not go further in detail. Apparently I needed to. Try this code and tell me if you get  pressed and released outputs for bot of these mouseareas :)

Comment: Did you try mine? If not try it first.

Comment: I want to handle the pressed and released events simultaneously. So what your code does is, if you click on m1 you get m1 pressed and released only. What I want to get is m1 pressed, m1 released, m2 pressed, m2 released

Comment: Do you want to get pressed and released for *both* m1 and m2 when m1 is pressed/released?

Comment: Yes exactly, when m1 is pressed/released, you should get m1 pressed m2 pressed, m1 released m2 released. the order is not important for me