# QML MultiPointTouchArea Passthrough

Tags: qt, qml, qtwebengine

**Short Version**
Is there a way to in QML only to re-emit / ignore touch events selectively using the `MultiPointTouchArea`?

OR

Is there a way to block multitouch events via QML from the `QtWebEngine`?

**Background / What I've Tried**
I'm helping with a QT application that uses the `QtWebEngine` 1.0 and when a multitouch gesture is applied to it, it crashes.

My initial plan was to drop a `MultiPointTouchArea` in front of the WebEngine and consume all of the gestures that were greater than 1 touch.  I was hoping to achieve this solely in QML (below) and the touch events less than two (single finger / mouse) would fall through to the WebEngine.

It didn't work :|  All of the touch events were consumed by the `MultiPointTouchArea`, which was tested by adding `TouchPoints` with rectangles around them to see which ones were firing.

To confirm that it wasn't WebEngine just not responding, I put a second MultiPointTouchArea under the min:2 one and was never able to it's touch events.

```
MultiPointTouchArea {
    z:10
    anchors.top: parent.top
    width: parent.width
    height: parent.height
    enabled:true 
    mouseEnabled:true
    minimumTouchPoints: 2
    onPressed: { console.log("multi touch pressed"); }
}
```

A similar issue was asked here: [Object to process touch event but also let it through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35312255/object-to-process-touch-event-but-also-let-it-through), but they were able to Subclass / recompile.